# changing std::vector<double> debugger view

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, vector, copy-paste

It is possible to extend visual studio (2012) debugger as shown in many places (e.g. [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/07/12/10329460.aspx), [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Writing-type-visualizers-2eae77a2) and most important [here](http://bit.ly/16FxclN)). I'm trying to change how the debugger shows `std::vector<double>`. My goal is when I copy paste the data from the vector in the watch window to another program (e.g. Matlab, excel,etc) the data would appear as a list of values instead of a table with additional data.

For example, in the current status when I copy-paste data from vector I get this:

```
        [0] 94.024513667772339  double
    [1] 104.70544392511518  double
    [2] 121.33423324928492  double
    [3] 132.01724343105604  double
    [4] 148.59977457595494  double
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
94.024513667772339  
104.70544392511518  
121.33423324928492  
132.01724343105604  
148.59977457595494
```

Can this be accomplished using the custom debugger?